# Manipulating a Local File with SQL-Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to using Oracle SQL developer. While I am able to use it to connect to DBs and run queries, I wonder if I can manipulate local datasets using the tool? For example, if I have a file "C:\Some.csv", can I use SQL developer to manipulate the file locally (if so how?) or will I have to import all local files to the database servers before operating on it?

I was using SAS mostly in the past and it was capable of doing that. If it cannot can you please advise on SQL/data tools that can perform that locally? Now I am figuring my way around SQL developer so would appreciate all your valuable advices.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of manipulation? Reading data from the file and storing it in the database (SQL*Loader)? Or writing query results (spool from SQL Developer)? Or something else?

Comment: What does "manipulate" mean? If you want help, you need to be specific about what you're asking. Notepad can "manipulate" a text file, but I doubt that's what you mean, so **be more specific** about what you're asking.

Comment: Reading data from the file, extracting rows based on particular filters, adding or subtracting columns, etc. Basically trying to accomplish these tasks without having to import the local file onto the databases. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create jdbc connections to excel, delimited files, etc.

CSV/Excel support is limited to exporting grids TO that format, and reading in those files to load into a new or existing Oracle table.